# How to run modules directly in anaconda python distribution?

Tags: python, kivy, anaconda

I have installed kivy. But when I enter kivy in the console I get the following.

'kivy' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

I am trying to run the following.

kivy -m pip install -U watchdog pygments docutils jedi gitpython six kivy-garden

Comment: wich operating system are you on?

Comment: Seems like windows(batch file), but why do you use `kivy`? do you use 1.8.0 portable package or something?

Comment: I am on windows
and trying to run this
https://github.com/kivy/kivy-designer